# Trying to avoid mutating a prop that goes 3 levels deep by using $emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, modal-dialog, primevue

EDIT: [Here's a repo](https://github.com/drpcken/stackFix) I made for easier parsing.

I have a Component that lists products in a datatable.  The first column of the table is a link that shows a modal with a form of the product that was clicked (using its ID).  I'm using the PrimeVue library for styling and components.

```
<template>
   <Column field="id" headerStyle="width: 5%">
     <template #body="slotProps">
        <ProductForm :product="slotProps.data" :show="showModal(slotProps.data.id)" />
           <a href="#" @click.stop="toggleModal(slotProps.data.id)">
              <span class="pi pi-external-link"> </span>
           </a>
     </template>
   </Column>
</template>

<script>
import ProductForm from "./forms/ProductForm";

export default {
  data() {
     return {
       activeModal: 0,
     }
  },
  components: { ProductForm },
  methods: {
    toggleModal: function (id) {
      if (this.activeModal !== 0) {
        this.activeModal = 0;
        return false;
      }
      this.activeModal = id;
    },
    showModal: function (id) {
      return this.activeModal === id;
    },
  },
</script>
```

The modal is actually a sub component of the ProductForm component (I made a template of the Modal so I could reuse it).  So it's 3 components all together (ProductList -> ProductForm -> BaseModal).  Here's the product form:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <BaseModal :show="show" :header="product.name">
      <span class="p-float-label">
        <InputText id="name" type="text" :value="product.name" />
        <label for="name">Product</label>
      </span>
    </BaseModal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BaseModal from "../_modals/BaseModal";

export default {
  props: ["product", "show"],
  components: { BaseModal },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```

When the modal pops up it uses the ProductForm subcomponent.  Here is the BaseModal component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Dialog :header="header" :visible.sync="show" :modal="true" :closable="true" @hide="doit">
      <slot />
    </Dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    show: Boolean,
    header: String,
  },
  methods: {
    doit: function () {
      let currentShow = this.show;
      this.$emit("showModel", currentShow)
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I'm passing the `product` object, and a `show` boolean that designates if the modal is visible or not from the first component (ProductList) all the way down through the ProductForm component and finally to the BaseModal component.  The modal is a [PrimeVue component called `Dialog`](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase-v2/#/dialog).  The component actually has it's own property called "closable" which closes the modal with an X button when clicked, that is tied to an event called `hide`.  Everything actually works. I can open the modal and close it.  For some reason I have to click the another modal link twice before it opens after the initial.

The issue is when I close a modal, I get the `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "show"` error.  I've tried everything to emit to the event and change the original props value there, but the error persists (even from the code above) but I'm not sure if because I'm 3 components deep it won't work.  I'm pretty new to using props and slots and $emit so I know I'm doing something wrong.  I'm also new to laying out components this deep so I might not even be doing the entire layout correctly.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are emitting the `showModel` event from `BaseModal` but you are not listening for it on the parent and forwarding it+listening on grandparent (`ProductForm`)

But the main problem is `:visible.sync="show"` in `BaseModal`. It is same as if you do `:visible="show" @update:visible="show = $event"` ([docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)). So when the `Dialog` is closed, PrimeVue emits `update:visible` event which is picked by `BaseModal` component (thanks to the `.sync` modifier) and causes the mutation of the `show` prop inside `BaseModal` and the error message...

Remember to **never use prop value directly with `v-model` or `.sync`**

To fix it, use the prop indirectly via a [computed with the setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter):

`BaseModal`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Dialog :header="header" :visible.sync="computedVisible" :modal="true" :closable="true">
      <slot />
    </Dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    show: Boolean,
    header: String,
  },
  computed: {
    computedVisible: {
      get() { return this.show },
      set(value) { this.$emit('update:show', value) }
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Now you can add same computed into your `ProductForm` component and change the template to `<BaseModal :show.sync="computedVisible" :header="product.name">` (so when the `ProductForm` receives the `update:show` event, it will emit same event to it's parent - this is required as Vue event do not "bubble up" as for example DOM events, only immediate parent component receives the event)

Final step is to handle `update:show` in the `ProductList`:
`<ProductForm :product="slotProps.data" :show="showModal(slotProps.data.id)"  @update:show="toggleModal(slotProps.data.id)"/>`

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'm about to work on this (didn't want you to think I read your comment and didn't' appreciate it).  I'm very new to working with props and sending them back up to parents/grandparents.  You explained this very well.  Thank you!

Comment: This worked beautifully!  Just so I understand... to carry the prop all the way from the BaseModal to its grandparent, I need to add and $emit the computed property in every component along the way?